# Cannot invoke 'completion' with an argument list of type '(success: Bool, error: NSError?)'

Tags: swift, completionhandler

I have a completion handler in a HealthKit enabled app using a previous version of Swift.  It's giving me issues with the new version of completion handlers in Swift 4.0.

Getting the error:

> Cannot invoke 'completion' with an argument list of type '(success: Bool, error: NSError?)'

My code looks like this:

```
healthKitStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: healthKitTypesToRead) { (success, error) -> Void in
    if( completion != nil ) {
        completion(success:success,error:error! as! NSError)
    }
}
```

How should this look with the new completion handler?  Having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around this.

Comment: Should your method signature. Btw why do you declare your completion handler as optional? And why do you cast your error as NSError. Just return the error as it is (no cast or unwrapping is needed). `completion(success, error)` and don't check completion against nil

Answer (score 0):

`completion` cannot be `nil`, since it's not an `Optional`, its type is `(Bool,Error?)->Void`, so your if statement is not valid.

This is how to check if your authorization request was successful or not:

```
healthKitStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: healthKitTypesToRead) { success, error in
    guard error == nil, success else {
        print(error);return
    }
    //You can start using HealthKit data
}
```

It seems like you are implementing your own wrapper function around `HKHealthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare:read:completion)`. The issue with that seems to be that you named your own closure input parameter `completion` as well, which is also the name of the closure parameter for the function you are wrapping. You should change the name of your own parameter to something other than `completion`. You also shouldn't cast `error` to `NSError`, why not keep the type as `Error`?